# Disqus Comments System is overlapping my wordpress footer. Really need help?

Tags: wordpress, disqus

Good day wordpress/css/html experts!

I'm currently developing my own theme using an online tutorial. All went well until i encountered an issue with the comments page.

I copy pasted the codes from Disqus.com. The problem is, when i tested commenting on my own blog (after 5 test comments), it overlaps my footer. My footer is under while the five comments is above.

Need help with this please.

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty div tag below the Disqus code and give it a class which has clear: both; as a style. That should push your footer down but it would help to see your footer HTML and CSS as well as the Disqus code or post a link to an example if possible. Your footer may be absolutely positioned or your content areas floating over the footer. Post some code for a better answer